# How to get static files to work on a server

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I'm following the pythonprogramming.net Django tutorials, and I'm really confused by the static files part. When I run it locally it works, but the css isn't working on the server. I'm running

```
nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/django
```

and it's returning the alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/media
which I'm putting into the STATIC_ROOT variable. Then when I run

```
   python manage.py collectstatic
```

it says they have been copied to the static location, but it doesn't show them when i refresh my ip.

here's the source code

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

SECRET_KEY = 'It's secret'


DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'personal',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT='/home/django/django_project/django_project/media;'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: If you use `python mananger runserver` in local, the Django build-in server will help you serve static file. When you are on a remote server, you need config nginx to serve your static file, and configure a WSGI server such as `gunicorn` to serve dynamic Django app.

Comment: Can you please post related part of your nginx configuration?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by nginx configuration. The only place i did anything with it was where i used it in the top part

Comment: @JakeSteele nginx is the webserver that you would use in production. The static files are served by your webserver(nginx). nginx configuration includes the configuration for your static files and hence it would be better if you could share it

Comment: `/etc/nginx/sites-available/django` file should contain your configuration, can you please add contents of that file to your question?